# Create order total based on 'n' number of textbox values?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, textbox

I have a web based inventory system. I am currently working on the Purchase Order section of the system that creates a new order for more inventory. First, the user enters a Supplier to order stock from. Then, he is directed to a page that lists all of the products that are carried by that supplier. The user is asked to select a number of the items to order and is then directed to a page that displays the items and their unit prices. The page also creates a text box next to each item where the user can enter the quantity to order. What I want to do next is have a javascript button that multiplies the entered quantity by the unit price for that item and displays it in another textbox in the next column. Then have a button that adds all of the item totals for an order total at the bottom. I would like to do all of this without leaving the page. (PS after this page, the information will be pasted into an Excel template using PHPExcel) Here is the code:

```
<html>
<title>Edit Purchase Order</title>
<?php 
    include("menu.php");
    include("sqlconnect.php");
?>
<body>
<table align='center' border='1'>
<tr><th>Supplier:</th>
<th>Item Number:</th>
<th>Size/Volume:</th>
<th>Color:</th>
<th>Wholesale Cost:</th>
<th>Quantity In Stock:</th>
<th>Item:</th>
<th>QUANTITY FOR ORDER:</th>
</tr>
<?php 
        foreach ($_POST[itemselect] as $id)
        {
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id='$id'");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    include("colors.php");
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $row[Supplier];
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $row[ItemNumber];
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $row[TypeSizeVolume];
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $row[Color];
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $row[WholeSaleCost];
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $row[QuaninInventory];
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $row[Item];
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "<input type='text' name='quantityfororder[]'><input type='hidden' name='rowid[]' value='$row[id]'>";
                    echo "</td></tr>";
                }
        }
?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you a million. I can't figure this out!!

Comment: So... you want me to teach you Javascript?

Comment: No, I fully understand javascript. But I need to have the quantity for order text boxes available using the post method for the next page. I dont know how to use javascript with php. Cut me some slack man, I just started coding like 5 days ago.

Comment: First, let me introduce you to an enemy of mine called [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). Next, you are running a separate query for each item that's posted, you should collect the ids, run the DB query once to fetch all the results and iterate that. Just saying...

Comment: Sorry if that last comment was a little bit... curt, but it had to be said. You should look at using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) if you aren't already, it will make this kind of DOM manipulation easy as pie ;-)

Comment: @DaveRandom how should I collect all of the id's and then make a query? They are stored in $_POST[itemselect]

Comment: @DaveRandom is it possible to mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id='$_POST[itemselect]'")?

Comment: Assuming your IDs are numeric (which they should be) I would do [this](http://codepad.org/ZGVfqaNq)

Comment: @DaveRandom That works perfectly! Thank you. How would you make a button that updates each item's total onclick in a new textbox beside the quantity one?

Comment: Well first things first, generate the HTML (including the button and all necessary inputs). If you do that and show some example output we can take a look at where to go with it.

Comment: @DaveRandom ok I made the HTML structure. Here is what I have http://codepad.org/jMbNxFTU

Comment: In retrospect I think it would be nicer from the user's point of view if you scrap the buttons and just bind to the keyup event for triggering the recalc, give me 10 mins i'll run up a quick jsfiddle example

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4PyVs/2/ - I am going to bed now so if you have any questions just post them here and I'll check back tomorrow.